# no me muestra la imagen que tengo en una ruta especifica aspx

Tags: c#, .net, aspx

estoy tratando de realizar varios esquemas con IF para poder mostrar determiadas imagenes la cuestion es que en mi codebehin lo tengo de esta forma la URL

```
    rssURL = "https://odm.com.mx/videowall/img/cabecera2.jpg";
```

pero no me muestra nada aqui adjunto evidencia
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora la forma en la que lo estoy llamando es la siguiente

```
 <asp:Image ID="rssURL" runat="server"  />
```

entonces no se que me falte para mostrar mi imagen de la ruta con aspx

Comment: `rssURL` es el control, tú tienes que poner la URL en una propiedad de ese control. `rssURL.ImageUrl="https://odm.com.mx/videowall/img/cabecera2.jpg"`

Comment: perfecto muchas gracias, ya le ajustare las propiedasdes de anchura etc gracias